# Dict of Dict from Pandas DataFrame with dates

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
date       AAC      AFE     AFS     AKD    MAF   PRE                                    
2020-04-05  0       10000   0       0      0     75000
2020-04-06  0       30000   10000   0      0     0  
2020-04-10  47000   33000   20000   0      2000  8700
2020-04-11  0       0   0   0       25000  0     0  
2020-04-16  0       0   0   0       50000  0     0  
2020-04-21  0       30000   25000   0   0  1000  0  
2020-04-30  0       122000  65000   0   0  1000  0
```

I am trying to create a dict of dict so that the resulting dictionary resembles the following format

```
{'2020-04-05': {'AAC': 0, 'AFE': 10000, 'AFS': 0, etc}
 '2020-04-06': {AAC: 0, 'AFE': 30000, 'AFS': 10000, etc}}
```

My current solution:

```
d = {date: {col: df[col].values for col in df.columns} for date in demand_df.index}
```

yields the wrong (column-wise/axis 1) results as I am not getting the correct value, per product per date

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with orient=index after `set_index` the column 'date':

```
print (df.set_index('date').to_dict(orient='index'))
{'2020-04-05': {'AAC': 0, 'AFE': 10000, 'AFS': 0, 'AKD': 0, 'MAF': 0, 'PRE': 75000}, 
 '2020-04-06': {'AAC': 0, 'AFE': 30000, 'AFS': 10000, 'AKD': 0, 'MAF': 0, 'PRE': 0}, 
 '2020-04-10': {'AAC': 47000, 'AFE': 33000, 'AFS': 20000, 'AKD': 0, 'MAF': 2000, 'PRE': 8700}, ...}
```

Comment: Perfect - thanks so much for the quick response, much appreciated!